# Why won't Steam work on my Dell INSPIRON E1705?

Tags: dell, steam, opengl

this is my first post, so I hope i'm doing it right; I recently got a used laptop from a friend of mine, it came with windows XP on it, oh the horror; I upgraded the OS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; and installed Steam,I than Downloaded Team Fortress 2, and tried booting it up, only to find an error saying there was a problem with my openGL drivers, I went through, updated the Drivers, rebooted, tried again, and.. same error glaring back at me from my screen, I suspect its probably a hardware compatibility issue, but, i don't know, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which graphics adapter driver are you using currently? Please [edit] your question to improve it with additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up your Dell Inspiron e1705 specs and it seems to me like the integrated graphics from Intel or the optional Nvidia graphics chip that comes with it are not powerful enough to run the game.
The minimum system requirements for Team Fortress 2 are:
Graphics: nVidia GeForce 8600/9600GT, ATI/AMD Radeon HD2600/3600 (Graphic Drivers: nVidia 310, AMD 12.11), OpenGL 2.1 
Your guess was correct, it's a hardware problem.